# Who sings "Open Your Mind"?

Tags: identify-this-song, dancing

Who sings the old 80s or 90s song "Open Your Mind", the one where you do all the slow dance around the mind of the (say, somewhat quiet) person whose mind you want to prop open to see inside?

P.S. What do you nowadays call what you used to call 'dance', in the nineties. I see there is no 'dance' tag. Is there something that replaces it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few dance-oriented songs from the 80s or 90s with a similar title:

- "[Open Your Mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPFAYIr8z2I)" by U.S.U.R.A. (1993)
- "[Open Your Mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCRPC-oZmgE)" by Kleeer (1980)
- "[Open Up Your Mind (Wide)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTWrn8mgt40)" by The Gap Band (1979)

I think it's still just "dance" music, maybe "club" music. I'm not sure why there isn't a tag for it at the moment, perhaps no one has asked a question about it yet?

Comment: Yeah, maybe there should be a 'club tag'. :-D . Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I guess club would be vague. I mean, a long time ago club still meant many music styles, depends on the club. Now even more.